# Font awesome - two circles around the icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to achieve effect shown on the second picture - namely the green icon. My current state is on the first picture (working on icon with heart symbol but that doesn't really matter).

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kimtp.png)
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWfdb.png)

Digging on problem I've decided to break it into parts:

1. Render base icon (with white color)
2. First circle around the icon (with desired color - red in this case)
3. Rectangle below the icon
4. Second circle around the icon (white again) - this should overpaint a part of rectange from point 3 to create the edges effect.

I've been able to complete first two points with my current code:

```
<i class=\"fas fa-heart fa-lg\"></i>
```

Where `fa-heart` is overriden like:

```
    .fa-heart {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    background: #d44d32;
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 18px !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3px;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Code is taken from my asp mvc app due to this first line of my code may look strange - I'm computing the icon state in view.

One possible solution I've found doing my research is to use stacked icons. I'd very much like to render entire effect using one icon - if possible.

Comment: Could you please explain reason of downvoting the Q?

Comment: I fail to reproduce with exactly your code and I do not understand how you get the heart-icon when you overwrote fa-heart. Also, it might help to get answers if you provided a fiddle where ppl could easily see the prob and work on it. I did one: https://codepen.io/MBaas/pen/oEVXMb?editors=1111

Comment: Strange, but that's just a slight detail. It works almost the same. If you change padding to like 6px, you will obtain desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your padding: `padding: 5px;` also, having `!important` in w/h is unadvised.